# Find the customers and other metrics based on the purchase frequency new & repeat

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the customer count and sales by the type of customer (New and Returning) and the number of times they have purchased.

```
txn_date Customer_ID  Transaction_Number    Sales        Reference(not in the SQL table)    customer type (not in the sql table)
1/2/2019    1           12345                $10           Second Purchase SLS                    Repeat
4/3/2018    1           65890                $20           First Purchase SLS                     Repeat      
3/22/2019   3           64453                $30           First Purchase SLS                     new
4/3/2019    4           88567                $20           First Purchase SLS                     new
5/21/2019   4           85446                $15           Second Purchase SLS                    new
1/23/2018   5           89464                $40           First Purchase SLS                     Repeat
4/3/2019    5           99674                $30           Second Purchase SLS                    Repeat
4/3/2019    6           32224                $20           Second Purchase SLS                    Repeat
1/23/2018   6           46466                $30           First Purchase SLS                     Repeat
1/20/2018   7           56558                $30           First Purchase SLS                     new
```

I am using the below code to get the aggregate sales and customer count for the total customers:

```
select seqnum,  count(distinct customer_id), sum(sales) from (
select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by txn_date) as seqnum
      from somya co)
 group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

I want to get the same data by the customer type:

for example for the new customers my result should show:

```
New Customers   Customer_Count   Sum(Sales)
1st Purchase        3               $80
2nd Purchase        1               $15


Returning Customers    Customer_Count     Sum(Sales)
1st Purchase                3                $90
2nd Purchase                3                $60
```

I am trying the below query to get the data for new and repeat customers:

New Customers:

```
select seqnum,  count(distinct customer_id), sum(sales)
from (
select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by trunc(txn_date)) as seqnum,
            MIN (TRUNC (TXN_DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as MIN_TXN_DATE
      from somya co
      )
      where MIN_TXN_DATE between '01-JAN-19' and '31-DEC-19' 
      group by seqnum
      order by seqnum asc;
```

Returning Customers:

```
select seqnum,  count(distinct customer_id), sum(sales)
from (
select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by trunc(txn_date)) as seqnum,
            MIN (TRUNC (TXN_DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) as MIN_TXN_DATE
      from somya co
      )
      where MIN_TXN_DATE <'01-JAN-19' 
      group by seqnum
      order by seqnum asc;
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my query or if there is a problem with my logic.

This is just a sample data, I have transactions from all the years in my data base so I need to narrow the transaction date in the query but as soon as I narrowing down the data using the transaction date the repeat customer query doesnt give me anything and the new customer query gives me the total customer for that period.

Comment: Do you really want the 4/3/2018 sale to customer 1 to be counted as his "first purchase" for a 2019 sales report?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak it should be counted as the first purchase sales under the repeat customers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to know the first time someone becomes a customer.  And then use this:

```
select (case when first_year < 2019 then 'returning' else 'new' end) as custtype,
       seqnum,  count(*), sum(sales)
from (select co.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id, extract(year from txn_date) order by txn_date) as seqnum,
            min(extract(year from txn_date)) over (partition by customer_id) as first_year
      from somya co
     ) s
where txn_date >= date '2019-01-01' and
      txn_date < date '2020-01-01'
group by (case when first_year < 2019 then 'returning' else 'new' end),
         seqnum
order by custtype, seqnum;
```

Comment: The sales should match the total sales in the table when we add the sales for new and returning customers. in this query its not producing the result which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @somya . . . This should match the sales for 2019, which is what the question appears to be asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can categorize your sales data to assign a customer type and a purchase sequence using windowing functions, like this:

```
SELECT sd.txn_date,
       sd.customer_id,
       sd.transaction_number,
       sd.sales,
       case when min(txn_date) over ( partition by customer_id ) < DATE '2019-01-01' 
             AND max(txn_date) OVER ( partition by customer_id ) >= DATE '2019-01-01' 
                  THEN 'Repeat' 
                  ELSE 'New' END customer_type,
       row_number() over ( partition by customer_id order by txn_date) purchase_sequence
FROM sales_data sd
```

> ```
> +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+
> | TXN_DATE  | CUSTOMER_ID | TRANSACTION_NUMBER | SALES | CUSTOMER_TYPE | PURCHASE_SEQUENCE |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+
> | 03-APR-18 |           1 |              65890 |    20 | Repeat        |                 1 |
> | 02-JAN-19 |           1 |              12345 |    10 | Repeat        |                 2 |
> | 22-MAR-19 |           3 |              64453 |    30 | New           |                 1 |
> | 03-APR-19 |           4 |              88567 |    20 | New           |                 1 |
> | 21-MAY-19 |           4 |              85446 |    15 | New           |                 2 |
> | 23-JAN-18 |           5 |              89464 |    40 | Repeat        |                 1 |
> | 03-APR-19 |           5 |              99674 |    30 | Repeat        |                 2 |
> | 23-JAN-18 |           6 |              46466 |    30 | Repeat        |                 1 |
> | 03-APR-19 |           6 |              32224 |    20 | Repeat        |                 2 |
> | 20-JAN-18 |           7 |              56558 |    30 | New           |                 1 |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+-------------------+
> ```

Then, you can wrap that in a common table expression (aka "WITH" clause) and summarize by the customer type and purchase sequence:

```
WITH categorized_sales_data AS (
SELECT sd.txn_date,
       sd.customer_id,
       sd.transaction_number,
       sd.sales,
       case when min(txn_date) over ( partition by customer_id ) < DATE '2019-01-01' AND max(txn_date) OVER ( partition by customer_id ) >= DATE '2019-01-01' THEN 'Repeat' ELSE 'New' END customer_type,
       row_number() over ( partition by customer_id order by txn_date) purchase_sequence
FROM sales_data sd)
SELECT customer_type, purchase_sequence, count(*), sum(sales)
FROM categorized_sales_data
group by customer_type, purchase_sequence
order by customer_type, purchase_sequence
```

> ```
> +---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
> | CUSTOMER_TYPE | PURCHASE_SEQUENCE | COUNT(*) | SUM(SALES) |
> +---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
> | New           |                 1 |        3 |         80 |
> | New           |                 2 |        1 |         15 |
> | Repeat        |                 1 |        3 |         90 |
> | Repeat        |                 2 |        3 |         60 |
> +---------------+-------------------+----------+------------+
> ```

Here's a full SQL with test data:

```
with sales_data (txn_date, Customer_ID,  Transaction_Number,   Sales ) as (
SELECT TO_DATE('1/2/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 12345, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('4/3/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'), 1, 65890, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('3/22/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 3, 64453, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('4/3/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 4, 88567, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('5/21/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 4, 85446, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('1/23/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'), 5, 89464, 40 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('4/3/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 5, 99674, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('4/3/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'), 6, 32224, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('1/23/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'), 6, 46466, 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('1/20/2018','MM/DD/YYYY'), 7, 56558, 30 FROM DUAL ),
-- Query starts here
/* WITH */ categorized_sales_data AS (
SELECT sd.txn_date,
       sd.customer_id,
       sd.transaction_number,
       sd.sales,
       case when min(txn_date) over ( partition by customer_id ) < DATE '2019-01-01' AND max(txn_date) OVER ( partition by customer_id ) >= DATE '2019-01-01' THEN 'Repeat' ELSE 'New' END customer_type,
       row_number() over ( partition by customer_id order by txn_date) purchase_sequence
FROM sales_data sd)
SELECT customer_type, purchase_sequence, count(*), sum(sales)
FROM categorized_sales_data
group by customer_type, purchase_sequence
order by customer_type, purchase_sequence
```

#### Response to comment from OP

> > all the customers whose first purchase date is in 2019 would be a new customer. Any customer who has transacted in 2019 but their first purchase date is before 2019 would be a repeat customer

So, change

```
case when min(txn_date) over ( partition by customer_id ) < DATE '2019-01-01' 
AND max(txn_date) OVER ( partition by customer_id ) >= DATE '2019-01-01' 
THEN 'Repeat' ELSE 'New' END customer_type
```

to

```
case when min(txn_date) over ( partition by customer_id ) 
  BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-01' - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
THEN 'New' ELSE 'Repeat' END customer_type
```

i.e., if and only if a customer's first purchase was in 2019 then they are "new".

Comment: Why have you taken Jan 2019 as the min and max date ?

Comment: @Somya Your requirements for classifying customers as "repeat" vs "new" weren't clear to me.  The logic in my answer says that a customer is "repeat" if they had at least one transaction before 2019 and one in 2019 or later.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much but the logic is a little different, so for 2019 all the customers whose first purchase date is in 2019 would be a new customer. Any customer who has transacted in 2019 but their first purchase date is before 2019 would be a repeat customer. The query seems to be working on the mock data base I created for this question but does not work if I am using it on the actual data base just to find the repeat customers. it works fine with new customers.

Comment: Updated my answer.